# Combining multiple forms and reports in one page

Tags: zoho

Following the Zoho tutorials in their site , It seems they are out of date . According to this [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/EBcwB9BiOzQ)
It's not the same as the current version of the site . How do i embed a form and report ?

Answer (score 1):

there is 2 way.

1. using iframe
2. using page you can directly add form/report

Please refer this:

Or
https://www.zoho.com/creator/newhelp/pages/add_form.html